# Span of two vectors is the same as the Span of the linear combination of those two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Question: Let $\vec{u}, \vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Span{$\vec{u},\vec{v}$}=Span{$\vec{u}+\vec{v},\vec{u}-\vec{v}$}

I tried to approach this proof by finding a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ but I am confused as to how to approach the linear combination of the right hand side of the equation. I am lost. Please help!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the RHS is quite trivially a subset of the LHS.  Conversely, you can recover both $x$ and $y$ very easily from the vectors $x+y$ and $x-y$.  Namely, $1/2\cdot(x+y)+1/2\cdot(x-y)=x$.  Then once you have $x$, you can subtract it from $x+y$ to get $y$.  Thus we have the reverse inclusion.

Hence they are equal.

Comment: i get that you used $1/2$ as the scalar constants but how is it possible to subtract x in that same combination.? wouldn't i need another combination using $1/2 , -1/2$ to get y?

Comment: I guess, technically, it would be $(x+y)-[1/2(x+y)+1/2(x-y)]=y$.  But I simplified things for myself, by knowing that the span of a set of vectors is closed under taking linear combinations.  So, and again this much detail is usually suppressed once you are more familiar with these things, you can take as many linear combinations of linear combinations as you want.  If that makes any sense.  The point is, you can use anything you find in the span to take new linear combinations, sort of, ad infinitum.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

All linear combination of RHS can be represented as a linear combination of LHS and vice versa.

Span of LHS = $a\vec{x} + b\vec{y}$

Span of RHS = $c (\vec{x} + \vec{y}) + d (\vec{x} - \vec{y}) = (c+d) \vec{x} + (c-d) \vec{y}$

any scalars in LHS can be represented using $(c+d)$ and $(c-d)$ too.

Comment: Does this mean that the quantity of linear combinations $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ is the same as the quantity of linear combinations for $\vec{x}+\vec{y}$ and $\vec{x}-\vec{y}$?

Comment: It does not mean it is the same, it means it can be the same - you can get to the same combination both on LHS and RHS.